# UIImageView showing 'old' image

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have an app that shows a series of `UIImageView`s on a `ScrollView`. The app starts by loading a 'splash page' then transitioning to the first image to be shown. The image for the splash page is actually loaded into the `UIImageView` nib in Interface Builder.

The problem I am having is that I am trying to reuse this app for a different set of images (the app is basically a template). This includes the splash page. I have done everything I can think of to replace the splash page image including, of course, modifying the view in Interface Builder and loading a different image. However, the previous splash page image still appears briefly when I run the app in simulator.

I have also tried: reviewing the .xib file text; removing the build directory from the app.

Looking for any suggestions on how to make this old image go away.

**Edit:** I have also deleted the 'old' image from the project. So it seems as if it is still being stored somewhere. Have also deleted the icons from Simulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isn't it the Default.png ?

Comment: Actually, wait a minute. I deleted default.png which was the 'old' image that still shows up. I currently dont have a default.png. I'll try renaming the image I want to show up.

Comment: Hmm... so that did the trick. I'm still curious as to how the other image still showed up.